# Swift, Unable to get Firebase Storage url to Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

I don't know why I can't get the URL but still, the image is uploaded to the Firebase Storage

```
func uploadThumbnail(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?)->())) {
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid!).child(titleTF.text!).child("thumbnail")
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) {
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            if error == nil, metaData != nil {
                storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                    completion(url)
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func doneTap(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let image = uploadImage.image else{ return }

    uploadThumbnail(image) { (url) in
        self.newPlayground(imageURL: url!)
    }
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

func newPlayground(imageURL: URL) {
    let newPlayground = Playground(title: titleTF.text!, price: "\(priceTF.text!) AED", location: locationTF.text!, description: descriptionTF.text!, images: "", thumbnail: imageURL, city: cityTF.text!, key: key!)
    newPlayground.save()
}
```

the newPlayground function suppose to update the database but it isn't running, any suggestion?

Comment: Go to your Firebase Console. do you see the image uploaded?

Comment: did you debug your program? Its easy to detect where it goes. at least add that to the question.

Comment: @AngryWarden yes, the image is uploaded to storage, but the newPlayground function isn't running, the function works fine but I can't get the url

Comment: @hasan yes, there is no url

Comment: @user1512238 Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger. Please set breakpoint on all important lines in this code, and run it through a debugger. Then describe precisely what happens on each line. For example, on `if error == nil, metaData != nil {` what is the value of `error` and of `metaData`? If `error` has a value, what is it? Does the debugger reach `completion(url)` or `completion(nil)`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did debug and set breakpoints, I have no idea why the code inside of storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) isn't running but this line works, I've tried to set a breakpoint inside but it would go over it and not break

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint on `if error == nil, metaData != nil {` is doesn't get hit? But the image is written to Storage correctly?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, even if I write storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) with no completion block the image will be written to storage